# Assaulting a city with atmospheric re-entry heat

Tags: warfare, engineering

In my world, a large empire (A) is at war with another empire (B). So far, both the sides are at a stalemate, with no gains or losses on either sides. That is when a engineer from "A" learns about atmospheric re-entry and the immense amount of heat it causes. So this engineer comes up with a plan.

Large boulders are sent up on rockets powered with primitive propellants (saltpeter+sugar) from a tall mountain, and go just midway to space (~50km) and after reaching the required altitude, the rockets break apart and the rocks fall to earth. While falling, they attain such a high speed that they start burning up in the air.

The idea here is to replicate the Chicxulub debris re-entry: When the asteroid struck, it kicked up a lot of debris, which went to space and fell back to earth. When the debris fell back to Earth, the re-entry heat created a heat pulse (see [this](http://annesastronomynews.com/new-evidence-about-asteroid-that-killed-the-dinosaurs/)), raising the surface temperature to something like 400°C, killing the dinosaurs.

Similarly, the heat produced by the reentry of these boulders launched by A, should also cause the air around B to become unbearably hot, incinerating everything.This idea came from this [video](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxoibVAKklitDDbVNUVWpU2_Y5PK8ZNwdE)

**Is this plan plausible? If no, then what improvements are needed for this solution to work?**

**Additional info:**

Technology- Imperial China (late Qing Dynasty)

Empire A is a empire located on the ground, whereas Empire B is located on a giant plateau about 7000m high.

Comment: Any tech that could lift a boulder in the manner described could better be used in far more ways and greater effect to your end goal. And by the time any rock returns to the surface just letting terminal velocity do the job, heat will be a minor issue to the target.

Comment: Has A considered just launching rockets directly at B? By all accounts, medieval China was rather creative in that area.

Comment: *"While falling, they attain such a high speed that they start burning up in the air":* They don't. The terminal velocity of a rock falling from any height greater than about 500 meters or 1500 feet (but still within the atmosphere) is not more than about 300 km/h (200 mph). See [XKCD What-If #58](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/). If you want the rocks to come really really fast so as to burn in the atmosphere you need to throw them waaaay higher, say 2000 km or so.

Comment: The re-entry principle is based on a Kurzgesagt video I watched a few days back, about the Chicxulub Impact. According to it, the debris falling back to earth caused the atmosphere to be heated up to extreme temperatures killing the dinosaurs

Comment: How do they breathe effectively, 7 knm. above gthe surface?

Comment: I really hate to say it, I'm just making a point, but you're using the word "medieval" and phrase "huge rockets" in the same post with the phrase "Is this plan plausible?" Since the answer is, "you lost plausibility with the phrase 'huge rockets,'" can you express your question in a more meaningful way? Because in an imaginary world, the answer to the question "is this plausible" is always "yes."

Comment: @FuriousNukefrostArcturus - yes.  The Chicxulub impact involved, to start with, an enormous impactor hitting the earth and releasing, conservatively, ten thousand times as much energy as the total global nuclear weapons stockpiles.  Putting a few boulders a few km up is not remotely comparable.

Comment: This sounds kinda of like trying to have the primary damage from a bullet by having the heat burn them as it grazes them: roundabout and wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, most of the answers here are responding to the idea of dropping a big rock on the enemy from space, but that's not what the OP was asking for.

What OP wants is more like having a beach full of sand burning up in re-entry, shedding enough infrared radiation to start fires on the ground. Kinda like this: http://annesastronomynews.com/new-evidence-about-asteroid-that-killed-the-dinosaurs/

While this sounds cool as a plot device, it's not going to happen, even with current technology.

1. You would have to launch the debris well out of the atmosphere. The Chicxulub crater was more than 177 km across. It ejected material thousands of kilometers up, well outside of the atmosphere. For your purposes, you'd have to launch your material a lot higher than 50km. Remember that our spacecraft suffer re-entry burns because they're hitting the atmosphere at *orbital velocity*, not because of the height from which they're dropping.
2. The stuff would burn up in the upper atmosphere, but let's presume that it just burns up at 30km. This suffers from the inverse square law, where the heat is spread out over a large area, so you'd have to set a significant portion of the sky on fire for anyone on the ground to notice it. This means you'd have to throw a LOT of dirt into the sky, like at least an entire beach's worth of sand.
3. The energy of re-entry is just recouping the energy required to get the object out of the gravity well in the first place. Assuming perfect efficiency, then the rockets that launched the stuff out of the atmosphere would do far more damage to the launch pad than it did to the target castle. It's the same heat, and it's a lot closer to the ground on the way up.
4. Even if you CAN get that much rocketry together, aiming it would be a bitch. During the cold war, the estimates of accuracy of ICBMs was measured in miles.
5. If you can launch rocks out of the atmosphere, you could just launch them at the castle yourself and have a much more immediate and accurate effect, for FAR less fuel.

So, sorry, fun idea, but no, not rationally defensible.

Answer (score 9):

This is not going to work.

You need way more than a big rock falling from 50 km to create an appreciable fireball.

I have run some calculations in one of the many [asteroid impact calculators](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=5&distanceUnits=1&diam=10&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=1&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500) using a ball of iron 10 meter in diameter falling at 1 km/s, and I got this message:

> At this impact velocity ( < 15 km/s), little vaporization occurs; no fireball is created, therefore, there is no thermal radiation damage.

Just for a reference, escape velocity for Earth is 11 km/s, therefore you can't simply drop a rock from high enough and hope it will reach a speed anywhere closer to 15 km/s.

If I put the same ball of iron [falling at 15 km/s](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=5&distanceUnits=1&diam=10&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=1&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500), it would vaporize before creating a fireball

> The projectile bursts into a cloud of fragments at an altitude of 4650 meters = 15200 ft

The first [combination of parameters](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=10&distanceUnits=1&diam=50&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=20&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500) for which I am able to get a fireball is a meteor made of iron, diameter 50 meters and falling at 20 km/s. In that case at 10 km from the impact point there would be

> Visible fireball radius: 847 meters ( = 2780 feet )
>
> The fireball appears 19.2 times larger than the sun
>
> Thermal Exposure: 3.68 x 10^5 Joules/m2
>
> Duration of Irradiation: 11.1 seconds
>
> Radiant flux (relative to the sun): 33.1
>
> Effects of Thermal Radiation: Much of the body suffers first degree burns

Comment: For comparison: That calculater believes that a 55 meter / 27 km/s rocky [tunguska asteroid detonates with 18 megatons](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=5&distanceUnits=1&diam=55&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=3300&vel=27&velocityUnits=1&theta=28&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500) above the earch.

Comment: I think he was talking about recreating the re-entry of the dinosaur killer. That one is supposed to have thrown a massive amount of debris in the air, and the IR from re-entry was supposed to have raised surface temperatures to something like 400C. This would neither be a localized event (like something you could cook a castle with) or a small amount of energy. You could easily destroy the entire castle and the mountain it stood on with the energy required to get it into orbit.

Comment: Yeah about that

Comment: @RobertRapplean the dinosaur killer is in the several kilometers area in diameter.

Comment: @Trish, That was the asteroid impact, yes, but OP is describing re-entry firestorms: http://annesastronomynews.com/new-evidence-about-asteroid-that-killed-the-dinosaurs/

Answer (score 3):

### Asteroids that hit the ground

It takes [an asteroid between 25 and 1000 meters](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/asteroids/overview/fastfacts.html) to get any item to hit the ground and that category only creates local damage. [There's even a formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327689/130419).

The [Tunguska Event had an asteroid of about 55 meters (+-5m) diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event) detonating some 5-10 kilometers over the ground, knocking over trees in a circle that of about 52 kilometers in diameter - or *roughly* one kilometer per meter of asteroid diameter. And it was moving at 27 kilometers a second in the first place - about 2.5 times the Earth's escape velocity!

### fastest human objects?

Humans have so fat never managed to accelerate any item to that speed without the help of stellar objects: while the Parker Solar Probe will burn up at a speed of 192 kilometers per second, she is accelerating towards the sun as she does. Likewise, Helios is clocked at about 70 kilometers per second and was impacting the sun too. A manhole cover is *believed* to have reached 56 kilometers per second as a nuclear explosion drove it up into space, but it is just as likely to have turned metal vapor on the way. The fastest object that didn't need the sun or a nuke to speed up was Voyager - 17 kilometers a second - which used several planetary slingshots. The fastest man-made object in an atmosphere that did neither reenter or rely in vacuum to speed up into was X-43 at a measely 3 kilometers a second... and flying very close to space.

It takes a lot of technology to get items that fast.

### Weight of such a monster

Let's assume a sphere of rock that is the absolute minimum 25 meters in diameter. A sphere has the volume of $V=4/3 r^3$, standard rock asteroids have a density of $\rho=\pu{3300 kg/m^3}$, and their mass is $M=V\rho$, so we're talking 82.5 metric tons.

### Biggest Spacecraft

Modern humans can get [very heavy items into space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heaviest_spacecraft)... in multiple launches it's easy. The first item on the list that was a single launch item is actually the Space Shuttle - 122.7 metric tons. That's heavier that you want, but it took modern engineering to make it possible.

### First manmade item in space.

The very first manmade item in space was either ["Bumper" in 1949](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/explorer/bumper.html) or [MW 18014 in 1944](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MW_18014). Both used an A-4/V-2 rocket as the ascent stage.

## conclusion

While a natural catastrophe that destroys a city is possible, it isn't possible to do manmade "[Rods from Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment)" even with modern technology.

Comment: +1 also worth emphasising that conservation of energy means that the energy of a falling object can never exceed the energy required to loft it into the air in the first place.  Given that atmospheric resistance is proportional to the square of the speed, the faster the object goes (up or down) the more energy is wasted.  In other words, always more energy efficient to shoot as straight as possible at the target unless a ballistic trajectory is required to evade ancient imperial point defence.